# How to compare two datasets and extract the differences between them in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two datasets with the same attributes but in some of the rows the information is changed. I want to extract the rows in which the information has been changed.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please post representative sample data in a format that is easily digestible.

Comment: Provide some data sample and read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

pandas offers a rich API that you can use to manipulate data whatever you want. merge method is one of them. merge is high performance in-memory join operations idiomatically very similar to relational databases like SQL.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
print(df1)

   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,10,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
print(df2)
    A  B
0   1  4
1  10  5
2   3  6

df3 = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(),how='right', indicator=True)
print(df3)
    A  B      _merge
0   1  4        both
1   3  6        both
2  10  5  right_only
```

as you can see there is new column named **_merge** has description of how this row merged, both means that this row exists in both data frames , where right_only means that this row exist only on right data frame which in this case is **df2**
if you want to get only row had been changed than you can filter on _merge column

```
df3 = df3[df3['_merge']=='right_only']
   A   B      _merge
2  10  5  right_only
```

**Note:** you can do merge using left join by change **how** argument to left and this will
grap every thing in left data frame (df1) and if row exists in df2 as well then _merge column will show up both. take a look at [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) for more details